# MySQL - Merge Multiple JSON Values to a single JSON with sums

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I have a table that contains a JSON column in it, say for example

`CREATE TABLE test(jsonValue JSON)`

And I  have multiple values int it:

```
INSERT INTO test('{"a": 1}');
INSERT INTO test('{"a": 3}');
INSERT INTO test('{"b": 4}');
INSERT INTO test('{"b": 10}');
```

I would like to return a result where I merge all JSONs to a single one with the sum of the values in each JSON.
So Result should be

```
{ 
 "a": 4,
 "b": 14
}
```

OR, an easier solution (using JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE)

```
{ 
 "a": [1, 3],
 "b": [4, 10]
}
```

How can I do this?
I have little SQL knowledge and I can't seem to figure our how to write this query.
Any help will be very appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If you have a different question related to this one, please ask it in a new question. Answering with another question will not get you new answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easier solution (using JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE and MySQL variables):

```
SET @json = ( SELECT CONCAT( "'", GROUP_CONCAT( jsonValue SEPARATOR "','" ), "'" ) FROM test );
SET @q    = CONCAT( "SELECT JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE(", @json, ") AS JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE;" );
PREPARE stmt FROM @q;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Answer (score 1):

Somethig like this?

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECTAGG(f, s)
FROM (
         SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_KEYS(jsonValue), '$[0]')                                             AS f,
                SUM(JSON_EXTRACT(jsonValue, CONCAT('$.', JSON_EXTRACT(json_keys(jsonValue), '$[0]')))) as s
         FROM test
         GROUP BY f
     ) as t
```

Not so nice, but works.

Comment: Works good thanks!
How can I alter the query so that if I have 
{"a": 1, "b": 2}  (i.e. multiple values in each row) it will still work? Since in the query we are taking the first element when extracting. When I use wildcard insteadh of $[0] it returns a list of values ["a", "b"] and I don't understand how to continue from there. since the concat does not work.

I tried lots of variations with no success (posted an additional question and for some reason my post was deleted).

Comment: can it be  `{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}`?

Comment: Yes, Yes it can

Comment: In that case this solution will not help you. You need some kind of loop on every var in your JSON. It's little hard in mysql.